# filtering a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, collections, tags, ienumerable

i have a list of project objects:

```
IEnumerable<Project> projects
```

a **Project** class as a property called **Tags**.  this is a **int[]**

i have a variable called **filteredTags** which is also a **int[]**.

So lets say my filtered tags variable looks like this:

```
 int[] filteredTags = new int[]{1, 3};
```

I want to filter my list (**projects**) to only return projects that have ALL of the tags listed in the filter (in this case at least tag 1 AND tag 3 in the **Tags** property).

I was trying to use **Where**() and **Contains**() but that only seems to work if i am comparing against a single value.  How would i do this to compare a list against another list where i need a match on all the items in the filtered list ??

Answer (score 71, accepted):

EDIT: better yet, do it like that:

```
var filteredProjects = 
    projects.Where(p => filteredTags.All(tag => p.Tags.Contains(tag)));
```

EDIT2: Honestly, I don't know which one is better, so if performance is not critical, choose the one you think is more readable. If it is, you'll have to benchmark it somehow.

---

Probably `Intersect` is the way to go:

```
void Main()
{
    var projects = new List<Project>();
    projects.Add(new Project { Name = "Project1", Tags = new int[] { 2, 5, 3, 1 } });
    projects.Add(new Project { Name = "Project2", Tags = new int[] { 1, 4, 7 } });
    projects.Add(new Project { Name = "Project3", Tags = new int[] { 1, 7, 12, 3 } });

    var filteredTags = new int []{ 1, 3 };
    var filteredProjects = projects.Where(p => p.Tags.Intersect(filteredTags).Count() == filteredTags.Length);  
}


class Project {
    public string Name;
    public int[] Tags;
}
```

Although that seems a little ugly at first. You may first apply `Distinct` to `filteredTags` if you aren't sure whether they are all unique in the list, otherwise the counts comparison won't work as expected.

Comment: I think your `Intersect` way is clearer than your 'better yet' method

Comment: @AakashM: I really don't know and I'm trying to decide it right now. I don't like the `Count()` because it has to evaluate the tags `IEnumerable`, but I'm puzzled myself

Answer (score 4):

We should have the projects which include (at least) all the filtered tags, or said in a different way, exclude the ones which doesn't include all those filtered tags.
So we can use Linq `Except` to get those tags which are not included. Then we can use `Count() == 0` to have only those which excluded no tags:

```
var res = projects.Where(p => filteredTags.Except(p.Tags).Count() == 0);
```

Or we can make it slightly faster with by replacing `Count() == 0` with `!Any()`:

```
var res = projects.Where(p => !filteredTags.Except(p.Tags).Any());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = projects.Where(p => filtedTags.All(t => p.Tags.Contains(t)));
```

Comment: Why? It won't allow project with tags "1, 2, 3" or am I missing something?

Comment: i am not sure ALL is correct as it need to work if it has ATLEAST 1 and 3 but it can have more than that  . . . isn't All() going to validate every item in the list against 1 & 3 ??

Comment: we can slightly modify the above code to achieve the desired result. 
var result = projects.Where(p => filtedTags.All(t => p.Tags.Contains(t))

Comment: @ooo @nyinyithann: Sorry my English is poor so I misunderstood OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

```
var filtered = projects;
foreach (var tag in filteredTags) {
  filtered = filtered.Where(p => p.Tags.Contains(tag))
}
```

The nice thing with this approach is that you can refine search results incrementally.

Comment: The bad thing with this approach is that you will loop all the projects many times (as many times as tags filtered you have). While the approaches above loop the projects only once. And while in most scenarios they will perform the same, in some common cases (think of projects using IEnumerable with yield or IQueryable) they will perform significantly better.

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b,

EqualAll is the approach that best meets your needs.

```
public void Linq96() 
{ 
    var wordsA = new string[] { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry" }; 
    var wordsB = new string[] { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry" }; 

    bool match = wordsA.SequenceEqual(wordsB); 

    Console.WriteLine("The sequences match: {0}", match); 
}
```

Comment: -1 I think your answer wrong and confusing (due to assuming that people will go to the link and read the samples and understand that EqualAll is the name they give in the page to sample the SequenceEqual method). And SequenceEqual won't work for this case because the "projects" can have more tags than the ones filtered and still should be considered a successful match.