# Filter ICollection of objects where any criteria matches the ones from a list of ints usin Linq

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have an object (Activity) with a collection of Category objects. I want to retrieve only the activities that match at least one category ids I get back from the query-string int the form of a List.

So we have:

- Activity Object with a collection (ICollection) of Category objects
- The Category object has a property named CategoryId
- From the query-string i get a list of ints (List) which represent CategoryIds

Now i would like to have a Linq query which returns all Activity objects that match at least on of the CategoryIds from the querystring.

Update 1

I tried: [filtering a list using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090568/filtering-a-list-using-linq)
But this needs to an object to filter by.

Update 2

The Linq Intersect command does the trick - this was an unknown command - really happy now!

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service: what have you tried?

Comment: @Richard - I have been trying with .Any and .Contains but that only seems to work on Object level and not if i need to match a property of the Category Object.

Comment: What about using [Enumerable.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Where` + `Intersect` + `Any`:

```
var query = activities
   .Where(a => a.Categories.Select(c => c.CategoryId).Intersect(yourIdList).Any());
```

another (less efficient) way is using `Enumerable.Any` + `Contains`:

```
var query = activities
    .Where(a => a.Categories.Any(c => yourIdList.Contains(c.CategoryId)));
```

Comment: thank you this works like a charm. I need to dig into the Intersect function because i want to understand how everything works :).