# Filter list with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class :

```
public class Car
{
    public string Color { get; set; }

        public string Speed { get; set; }
}
```

And one instance :

```
List<Car> Cars = new List<Car>()
{
     new Car()
     {
           Color = "Green".
           Speed = "100"
      }, 
      new Car()
     {
           Color = "Yellow".
           Speed = "150"
      }
}
```

I want to filter this List

I do :

```
List<Car> Conditions = new List<Car>()
{
     new Car()
     {
           Color = "Green".
           Speed = "100"
     }, 
     new Car()
     {
           Color = "Yellow".
           Speed = "100"
     }, 
     .......
}
```

How to browse my list and take only the car which corresponds at least to a condition with Linq?

Here, take only the first index of my list for example

My expected output :

```
  List<Car> Cars = new List<Car>()
    {
         new Car()
         {
               Color = "Green".
               Speed = "100"
          }
    }
```

Because Color AND Speed match with one index of `Conditions`

Comment: On what condition do you want to filter? What is the expected output? And last but not least, what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filtering a list using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090568/filtering-a-list-using-linq)

Comment: Firstly try to read something about LINQ. Sone examples here:
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-tutorials
or here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
var FilteredCars = Cars
    .Where(car => Conditions.Any(c => car.Color == c.Color && car.Speed == c.Speed));
```

If `Car` would override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` in this way you could also use this:

```
var FilteredCars = Cars.Where(Conditions.Contains);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need set of cars

```
var result = Cars
    .Where(car=>Conditions.Any(cond=>
        cond.Speed == car.Speed && cond.Color == car.Color)).ToArray();
```

If you need only one car from set of matches to your condition

```
var result = Cars
    .FirstOrDefault(car=>Conditions.Any(cond=>
        cond.Speed == car.Speed && cond.Color == car.Color));
```

Comment: "How to browse my list and take only the car which corresponds at least to a condition with Linq?" So `var result = Cars
    .FirstOrDefault(car=>Conditions.Any(cond=>
        cond.Speed == car.Speed && cond.Color == car.Color))`