# Using linq to filter sharepoint-lists with sublists

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint-online, csom

I have a problem that I can't fix with my rather small LINQ knowledge.

I have a collection of lists that contain a list of fields. 
I need only the lists with the properties hidden == false and that got fields with the description "Special Field".

I tried the following approaches... none of them worked:

```
clientContext.Load(listCollection,
lists => lists
.Where(list => list.Hidden == false)
.SelectMany(list => list.Fields)
.Where(field => field.Description == "Special Field"));
```

and

```
var listQuery = from list in listCollection.Where(l => l.Hidden == false)
from field in list.Fields
where field.Description == "Special Field"
select list;
```

and

```
var listQuery2 = listCollection
.SelectMany(lists => listCollection)
.Where(l => l.Hidden == false)
.SelectMany(fields => fields.Fields)
.Where(f => f.Description == "Special Field"
```

all followed by

```
var result = clientContext.LoadQuery(listQuery2);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

None of them worked.

I get the following exception (for the last query but message is similar to the other querys):

> The query expression 'value(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCollection).SelectMany(lists => value(docma.Library.Classes.SharepointDataConnector+<>c__DisplayClass56_0).listCollection).Where(l => (l.Hidden == False)).SelectMany(fields => fields.Fields)' is not supported.

Does anybody clue what I am doing wrong or how to get it to work?

Do I need to use 2 queries?

Performance is important.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its a field collection which behaves like a List<>.  The hidden property applies to the list, the description to field. Structure is like List<SharepointList>.Hidden
and inside the list you have a list of fields with the description property. List<Sharepoint>.List<SharepointField>Fields. I hope thats not confusing :)

Comment: Can you show us how your `listCollection` looks like?

Comment: "None of them worked" isn't an error description. What was the problem? Compiler error? Not the results you expected? An Exception?

Comment: @lephro Did you add at the top of your file `using System.Linq;`? (just to be sure)

Comment: Please share your model Also

Comment: Refer this  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93973/linq-query-that-filters-elements-from-a-list-of-object And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090568/filtering-a-list-using-linq

Comment: Description of the ListCollection:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listcollection.aspx

I add the exeption to the question sorry for not providing it in the first place)

Comment: using System.Linq; is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) is not supported by [LINQ to SharePoint provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee535491(v%3Doffice.14))

To retrieve the following data

> I need only the lists with the properties hidden == false and that got
>   fields with the description "Special Field".

you could utilize the following query via [`ClientContext.LoadQuery` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.loadquery.aspx):

```
var lists = ctx.Web.Lists;
var result = ctx.LoadQuery(lists.Where(list => list.Hidden == false).Include(l => l.Fields.Where(f => f.Description == "Special Field")));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

or

```
var lists = ctx.Web.Lists;
var result = ctx.LoadQuery(lists.Where(list => list.Hidden == false).Include(l => l.Title,l => l.Fields.Where(f => f.Description == "Special Field").Include( f => f.Title, f => f.Description)));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

where you could specify *what properties needs to be returned* like `List.Title`, `Field.Title` and `Field.Description` is this case

**Update**

To return *only* lists which contains a *specific* field, the following filter could be applied:

```
var foundLists = result.Where(l => l.Fields.Count > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! This helped me a lot.
But I still get lists in the result that dont have any "Special Fields". For example i get a list "Documents" with no fields returned (cause there are no "Special Fields"). Is there a way to filter these lists out so that i get only lists that really contain "Special Fields" ?

Comment: Iam still looking for a solution. Does anybody has a clue what i can search for?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought about checking the field count, but this is even more elegant.